# Explicit Localization

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I'm using explicit localization in my pages, like in:

```
<asp:Literal ID="appTitle" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:TranslationResource, AppTitle %>"></asp:Literal></div>
```

If the AppTitle resource does not exist, is there any way to avoid "parser error" and to show a empty string or the resource name?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `GetGlobalResourceObject`, which does the same thing but returns null, rather than throwing an exception, if the key does not exist.

```
<div><%= GetGlobalResourceObject("TranslationResource", "AppTitle") %></div>
```

You can easily add a fallback value using the null-coalescing operator:

```
<div><%= GetGlobalResourceObject("TranslationResource", "AppTitle") ?? "No translation resource" %></div>
```

---

If you need to modify the behavior of the localization provider in a centralized way (without needing to modify the syntax used in the pages), you can override `resourceProviderFactoryType`.  Add the type to the web.config *globalization* section ...

```
<globalization resourceProviderFactoryType="MyLocalizationProvider"/>
```

And create `MyLocalizationProvider` by sub-classing `ResourceProviderFactory`.

Comment: Hello, about your first solution:

It did not work for me. First, I got a parser error again, "Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.". After, I took away the "runat='server'" tag and it compiled, but in execution time I got no return for the resource.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @user1684009 you don't need the `asp:Literal` server control, just put it inline in the markup (ie, inside the HTML div).  I should have made that clearer.

Comment: Now, it's ok! Instead of using '=', I put '#'. Thanks again.